# How to attach a file as stdin for the docker container?

Tags: python, docker, stdin

I am running a docker container that reads a csv file, transposes the dataframe and returns a csv. I am not understanding how to attach the csv file to be read by the docker container as stdin. When I run the following command `docker run --rm -i -v C:\Users\EngineerA\containerpython\container.py -v C:\Users\EngineerA\containerpython\file.csv/file.csv container python C:\Users\EngineerA\containerpython\container.py file.csv` I get the error that `can't find '__main__' module in '//C:\\Users\\EngineerA\\containerpython\\container.py`. Another command I tried to run was `cat ./file.csv | docker run -i container` but I get the error `can't open file '//container.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Here's my code:
Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest 

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
RUN pip install pandas
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

CMD ["python", "container.py"]
```

container.py

```
import argparse
import contextlib
import io
from typing import IO
import sys

import pandas as pd

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('FILE')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    with file_ctx(args.FILE) as input_file:
        data = pd.read_csv(input_file, index_col=0)
        df = data.transpose()
        df.to_csv("C:\\Users\\EngineerA\\containerpython\\out.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def file_ctx(filename: str) -> IO[bytes]:
    if filename == '-':
        yield io.BytesIO(sys.stdin.buffer.read())
    else:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            yield f


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You redirect input to stdin with Docker just like any other shell command; you just need to ensure you use the `-i` flag to keep stdin attached. For example, piping from another command:

```
$ echo hello world | docker run -i --rm docker.io/alpine:latest sed s/hello/goodbye/
goodbye world
```

Or reading from a file:

```
$ docker run -i --rm docker.io/alpine:latest grep root < /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
```

It doesn't matter whether you're running a Python program, a shell script, or something else.

If you're getting errors about `container.py`, that has nothing to do with reading from stdin.

Comment: For some reason the < in the command makes my vscode terminal malfunction. In the command ```docker run -i --rm docker.io/alpine:latest grep root < /etc/passwd``` where is the file path that you want to feed as stdin to the container. My container's name is container. If you could write a piece of line that works for me I would be very grateful